# embedding a UIScrollView in a ViewController and no paging

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I am trying to embed a UIScrollView inside a UIViewController. I want scrolling and paging enabled. I have:

```
CGRect thirdRect=CGRectMake(0.0f, 50.0f, 200.0f, 200.0f);
self.myVC=[[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:thirdRect];
self.myVC.pagingEnabled=YES;
self.myVC.scrollEnabled=YES;
//[self.myVC setBackgroundColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];

UIImage *myImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"stina.jpg"];
UIImageView *jtImageView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage];
[self.myVC addSubview:jtImageView];
[self.view addSubview:self.myVC];
```

and here's a screenshot (no paging, scrolling):

[image]

but there is no scrolling / paging. Is there something I am doing wrong? Is this even possible?

thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your UIScrollView you should set the content size, then scrolling will start happening

```
self.myVC.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000,1000);
```

Give it a try

Comment: Nop, you just need to enable the paging and the scrolling should be paged, the size of the page is the same of that of the frame. However you need to implement a different onscreen control to show the current page called UIPageControl